# No está agregando espacios usando PadRight o PadLeft

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**Transfondo:**

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio "Windows Forms" que básicamente consulta información de una base de datos en MS-Access para generar un archivo de texto.

Estoy usando espacios para que el texto *"en el archivo de texto"* se vea centrado.

Ejemplo:

Si deseo que el siguiente texto se vea centrado:

```
string titulo = "Restaurante Napolitano La 26";
MessageBox.Show(titulo);
//Restaurante Napolitano La 26
```

Uso **[PadRight](https://www.dotnetperls.com/padright)** o **[PadLeft](https://www.dotnetperls.com/padleft)**, para obtener este resultado:

```
string titulo = "Restaurante Napolitano La 26";
titulo = titulo.PadLeft(20, ' ');
MessageBox.Show(titulo);
//              Restaurante Napolitano La 26
```

Pero no entiendo porqué no le está agregando los espacios.

Esta es una muestra del código que estoy usando.

```
// Voy concatenando el texto de la tabla.
string mensaje_a_imprimir = "";

// Valor de la fila-columna. Para este ejemplo, será el valor de la columna "RestauranteName".
string valor_a_imprimir = "";

// Variable que contiene estos datos:
DataTable tbl_result_sql;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RestaurantName                | NIT       | Ciudad    | RegimenComun  |
|-------------------------------|---------- |-----------|---------------|
| Restaurante Napolitano La 26  | NIT: 123  | City1     | Regimen Comun |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Asigno el valor a la variable.
valor_a_imprimir = tbl_result_sql.Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim();

// Lo asigno nuevamente, pero con los espacios adicionales.
// El número "40" se debe a que el ancho de la información es de máximo 40 caracteres "con espacios".
valor_a_imprimir = valor_a_imprimir.PadLeft((40 - valor_a_imprimir.Length), '.');

// Este es el contenido que tendrá el archivo de texto.
mensaje_a_imprimir += valor_a_imprimir + "\r\n";

// Generar archivo de texto.
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Nueva Carpeta\TextoPrueba.txt", mensaje_a_imprimir);
```

Mis preguntas son:

- ¿Por qué no obtengo los resultados esperados al usar PadRight / PadLeft?
- En caso de que haya otra alternativa, ¿qué puedo usar para agregar espacios a un string que me permita centrar el texto?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Espero evitar hacer cálculos complejos "ya que al final, el archivo de texto es una muestra de cómo va a quedar antes de imprimirse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el parámetro de padleft es la longitud del string que añade los caracteres faltantes para alcanzar dicha longitud ya sea a la izquierda o a la derecha.

para que funcione como quieres tienes que agregar la longitud actual del string:

```
 titulo = titulo.PadLeft(titulo.Length+20, ' ');
```

no se que quieres hacer aqui :

```
valor_a_imprimir = valor_a_imprimir.PadLeft((40 - valor_a_imprimir.Length), '.');
```

esto no va a hacer nada, si quieres limitar la longitud del string debes utilizar substr y no pad

```
  valor_a_imprimir.Substring(0,40);
```

Comment: Con la segunda opción pretendo solo aplicar ciertos espacios,pero con tu explicación, veo que lo estoy haciendo mal. Estoy realizando los ajustes basado en tu repuesta, pero creo que esta es la respuesta correcta. Voy a esperar un poco mas para aceptar alguna respuesta. Gracias

Comment: tal vez lo que quieras es Substring y no pad

Comment: Mike, no, no me refiero al substring :) no es para limitar la longitud del texto sino para aplicarle espacios al texto, generando un texto centrado.

Comment: pues vas a tener que usar padleft a prueva y error hasta que encuentres una longitud que te guste